# Android Fire Smoke and Liquid flow Like animation

Tags: android, animation, graphics, android-animation

I am trying to create a listview with right and left swipe actions,

What I am trying to achieve,

1. When the user right swipes, there should be a fiery smoke animation follows the swipe from left to right and fill the row, the fiery smoke should be something similar to the following picture [image: Fiery smoke]
2. Same way When the user swipes from left to right, there should be a water flow animation from right to left something similar to this pic,

[image: water fluid]

I am not expecting exact code example, just a starting point or some pointers on how to do these kinda animations, as I am very new to android animations.

Comment: If you are "very new" to android animations this is a very wrong starting point :-)

Comment: I agree but i am not doing this to learn, but my app demands such an animation

Comment: As a starting point, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html for View Animations